# Displaying all values of a List (text) field, whether checked or unchecked

Tags: 8, entities

[Drupal 8]

I have a List (text) field that allows multiple values, displayed as a check box list when editing. But when viewing the node, only the checked values are displayed.

**How can I display *all* values, with an indicator which ones are checked/unchecked?** Is this possible with theming?

What I found so far:

- For Boolean fields, I can select something like this under "Output format" (e.g., "✔ / ✖"), but this doesn’t seem to be possible for List (text) fields. I guess the workaround would be to use multiple Boolean fields, but this makes Views Exposed Filters harder to use.
- For Drupal 7, there is the module [Selected and unselected values formatter](https://www.drupal.org/project/selected_and_unselected_values_formatter) (via the question [*How to display all values of List (text) instead of just the selected ones?*](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/107666/9223))
- I could imagine (but didn’t try) it would be possible to create a View and display it instead of the field, but then quick-editing would no longer work for this field, as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily generate a field formatter to output what you need in drupal 8 ([generate field formatter](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/create-a-custom-field-formatter) => `drupal gpff` with drupal console) and get the result into a view.

Getting the field definition will allow you to get all possibles values (selected or not) for your list and display items as check or not considering the current node value.

```
$defs = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager')->getFieldDefinitions('{ENTITY_TYPE}', '{BUNDLE}');
$field_definition = $defs['{FIELD_NAME}'];
```

Your custom formatter will be available in views (and everywhere it is usable, node display etc.).

Comment: Nice! I will give it a try with my https://www.drupal.org/project/selected_and_unselected_values_formatter module.

Answer (score 1):

['Display Selected and Unselected'](https://www.drupal.org/project/display_selected_and_unselected) module - is one of the possible solutions for Drupal 8.